# DQL How to return all records when parameter is empty

Tags: symfony, dql

I am building a Symfony app where a user can make some search through a search form with many fields. Now my DQL query looks like this:

```
$users = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
      ->addSelect('u')
      ->from('AppBundle:User', 'b')
      ->where('u.Number = :Number **OR u.Number = :blank'**)
      ->andWhere('u.Code = :Code')
      ->setParameter('Number', $Number)
      ->setParameter('blank', $blank)
      ->setParameter('Code', $code)
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
```

The problem is that I want my request to return ALL records related to the criteria when a user leaves some fields blank. Right now no records are returned because the system thinks I want entries with particular "blank" criteria. I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you actually have 2 parameters in this case, which are: `Number` and `Code`. And if one of them is "blank", then you have the `blank` variable set ?

If this is the case, I think you should write your request like this:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->addSelect('u')
        ->from('AppBundle:User', 'b')

if ($Number != "")
  $query->where('u.Number = :Number')
        ->setParameter('Number', $Number);

if ($code != "") {
  if ($Number != "") $query->andWhere('u.Code = :Code');
  else $query->where('u.Code = :Code');
  $query->setParameter('Code', $code);
}

$users = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: It works!! And in case I have not 2 fields as it is now, but, say, 10 search fields, I need to write 10 if - else blocks, or even 10 * 10 blocks in order to justify every possible situation with user input, right? Or maybe there is any workaround for such a situation? Thank You

Comment: If you have multiple fields, you should put then in an array, so that you can replace the lines above with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Good advice, thank you. Is it possible to see any example of such realization? I am afraid it will take much time for me to get through this)))

Comment: I have no example at hand. But if you try something and it does not work, do not hesitate to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Expr class](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) in DQL to further structure query around 'blank' field submitted by user. Simple `if(!empty($field))` will do the trick

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
  ->addSelect('u')
  ->from('AppBundle:User', 'b')
  ->where('u.Number = :Number')
  ->andWhere('u.Code = :Code')
  ->setParameter('Number', $Number)      
  ->setParameter('Code', $code);

if(!empty($blank)){
  $query->andWhere($query->expr()->orX(
     $query->expr()->eq('u.Number', ':blank')
  ));
  $query->setParameter('blank', $blank);
}

$users = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: and what is the value of $blank should be? Now I set it like this: `$blank = "";` and still it thinks that I want blank entries from it and returns nothing((